# Predicting the class of an article

Tags: python, transform, svm, data-fitting

I have successfully trained an SVM on 7 different classes. I train the clf in another method that I then pass into test. What test does is accept a website, extracts the main article from the website and then classifies that article using the clf from train. I then proceed to clean the entire article, and once its cleaned, I try to fit transform and classify it, but its not working out as well as expected I keep getting different errors, which I have been trying to fix, but the latest error got me thinking I might be approaching this in fundamentally the wrong way.

```
def test(text_clf_svm):
    print "Analysing Webpage"
    #Gets the URL from the extension
    url = "https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/feb/15/corbyn-mcdonnell-tax-radical-labour"
    #Goose loaded
    g = Goose()
    #Extract the text and feed it to the classifier
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    article = article.cleaned_text
    article = clean(article)
    article =str(article)
    print "Vectorising Text"
    print "Predicting Political Bias"
    vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1.0)
    predicted_svm = text_clf_svm.predict(vect.fit_transform([article]))
    print predicted_svm
```

This is the latest error I get:

> (fyp) Lucass-MacBook-Pro:fyp lucasbenitez$ python final_fyp.py Training Analysing Webpage Cleaning Article Vectorising Text
>   Predicting Political Bias Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "final_fyp.py", line 114, in 
>       train()   File "final_fyp.py", line 66, in train
>       test(text_clf_svm)   File "final_fyp.py", line 38, in test
>       predicted_svm = text_clf_svm.predict(vect.fit_transform([article]))   File
>   "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py",
>   line 54, in 
>       out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py",
>   line 326, in predict
>       Xt = transform.transform(Xt)   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 893, in transform
>       _, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 762, in _count_vocab
>       for feature in analyze(doc):   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 241, in 
>       tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py",
>   line 207, in 
>       return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())   File "//anaconda/envs/fyp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py",
>   line 576, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(attr + " not found") AttributeError: lower not found

Any thoughts on how I couLd evaluate any single corpus, individually retrieved?

PD: I have tested the accuracy of the SVM on a 25% of the data and it give me a solid 80% accuracy, so the SVM is definitely not the problem

Comment: What is the `vect` that you do `fit_transform` on? A vectorizer?

Comment: I do `fit_transform` on the  article, which is meant to be a string

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry, I didn't see that `vect = CountVectorizer`.

Comment: theres a bit more code to this question, Ill ad the rest of it if you feel it can help solve the issue?

Comment: I haven't used Goose, before, but I assume that the cleaned`article` is just a string?

Comment: its a unicode object, but I can turn it into a string if that makes it easier it a single line of code